# Issues using Neo4j with Android

Tags: android, eclipse, neo4j

I've ran into a couple of issues when trying to link up the Neo4j server running locally to my android device. My current set-up includes adding the neo4j .jars into my android projects build path, however when I debug on the device I get a 
"Could not find class 'org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory"

I'm assuming the neo4j .jars files have not transferred across the the device. I also tried adding Neo4j in as a maven dependency but got Dalvik errors, can some1 help me out that has created an android application that uses Neo4j.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the [REST APi](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api.html) from Android, preferably the [cypher endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html).

You can use any kind of REST library for that, Restlet, RestEasy, Jersey and even a plain HttpConnection.